# How can I divide sum for a of two column for a certain condition in rails

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a result system.
How can I calculate this cgpa for a semster.

I'm trying to show the cgpa only those of which semester is searched along with subject detail.

Calculation for that cgpa is: `Sum(credit*gpa)/Sum(credit)`.

**I have saved credit*gpa in a column for subject table.**

I can find normal cgpa using

```
<small class="text-warning">cgpa = <%= Subject.sum(:cXgpa)/ Subject.sum(:credit) %></small>** But I need to find it for semester searched
```

**table is**

```
t.string "subject_name"
t.string "subject_code"
t.float "credit"
t.float "gpa"
t.float "cXgpa"
t.integer "semester_id"
```

**I tried this to find it**

```
<small class="text-warning">cgpa = <%=  Subject.pluck('sum(subjects.cXgpa) /    sum(credit)').where(:semester_id=>params[:semester]) %></small>
```

**But getting this Error**

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column subjects.cxgpa does not exist
```

LINE 1: SELECT sum(subjects.cXgpa) / sum(credit) FROM "subjects"

Comment: `<%=  Subject.pluck('sum(subjects.cXgpa) /    sum(credit)').where(:semester_id=>params[:semester]) %>` - is your param coming through as `params[:semester]` or `params[:semester_id]` ?

Comment: No I tried that didn't work

Comment: Try `Subject.where(:semester_id=>params[:semester]).pluck(:cXgpa, :credit).then { |a, b| a.sum.fdiv b.sum }`.

Comment: This also should work: `Subject.where(:semester_id=>params[:semester]).select("SUM(subjects.cXgpa) / SUM(subjects.credit) AS total").sum(&:total)`

Comment: What is the column stored as in the db? `cxgpa` or `cXgpa`?

Comment: cXgpa has value of = credit*gpa
db doesn't have cxgpa

Comment: renamed cXgpa to cxgpa and used

 
 
 
 Subject.where(:semester_id=>params[:semester]).select("SUM(subjects.cXgpa) / SUM(subjects.credit) AS total").sum(&:total)

from @iGian and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Subject.where(semester_id: params[:semester]).pluck("sum(cxgpa) / sum(credit)")
```

We should write hash as `{ key: value }` instead of using `=>` and you don't need to have `subjects` in your `sum` clause cause you are working on only 1 table

Comment: didn't work. somehow taking cXgpa as cxgpa so I just changed the column name to cxgpa